# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined" from a referenced attribute of a getElementsByTagName Object

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined

from this code (http://pastebin.com/Lrv8JfWK):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait until page is done loading
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var inputTagObjects = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var inputTagDefaultValues = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < inputTagObjects.length; i++)
        {
            // Only add input elements with a type and name attribute
            if(inputTagObjects[i].hasAttribute("type") && inputTagObjects[i].getAttribute("type") == "text" && inputTagObjects[i].hasAttribute("name"));
            {
                // Make sure the input element has a default value
                if(inputTagObjects[i].hasAttribute("value") == false)
                {
                    // Give an empty value attribute
                    inputTagObjects[i].setAttribute("value","");
                }
                // Assign default value to global array with the index of the input elements name
                inputTagDefaultValues[inputTagObjects[i].name] = inputTagObjects[i].value;

                // Assign Events
                inputTagObjects[i].onfocus = function()
                {
                    console.log(inputTagObjects[i].getAttribute("name") + " has been focused.");
                }
                inputTagObjects[i].onblur = function()
                {
                    console.log(inputTagObjects[i].getAttribute("name") + " has been blurred.");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Which is supposed to remove the values of these text inputs when focusing, and refill them if nothing was entered when blurring once completed. For now it should just output to console:

```
<body>
    <div id="form">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p><input type="text" name="firstName" value="First Name" /></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="lastName" value="Last Name" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it (without JQuery)?

Comment: Placeholders were invented for a reason.

Comment: @Adam Yup. And their reason is not as a substitute for proper labels :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the event handler is called, `i` is not set to the same thing as it was when it was assigned.

Try replacing `inputTagObjects[i]` with `this` inside the handler functions.

EDIT: Then again, you should NOT be using JavaScript for that. Here's a suggestion for a better way to render your form:

```
<p><label>First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="John" /></label></p>
<p><label>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Smith" /></label></p>
```

Comment: What is placeholder? is that valid HTML? Or are you still editing this?

Comment: It's HTML5. You know, modern stuff that makes you look like a clever person :p